# Docker: cannot copy file within the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cp

This is not about transferring files between host and container, it's just inside the container.

**app.js** exists in the build directory.

```
Step 7 : RUN ls build
 ---> Running in 8461a550a5db
app.js
app.js.map
css
html
img
js
 ---> 22a863b60265
```

Should be copied to the *static* folder.

```
Removing intermediate container 8e195477d342
Step 9 : RUN cp build/app.js static/
 ---> Running in 0a49669338e0
 ---> 41cb4d3039d1
```

But it's not there. Why?

```
Removing intermediate container 0a49669338e0
Step 10 : RUN ls static/
 ---> Running in 4cdb5f74a722
css
html
img
js
```

Tried: *RUN cp ./build/app.js ./static/* - doesn't work either.

Comment: can you post the entire dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to use docker build with no-cache?

```
docker build -t "your_app" --no-cache=true .
```

Problem here:

```
Removing intermediate container 0a49669338e0
```

From Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache

> During the process of building an image Docker will step through the
>   instructions in your Dockerfile executing each in the order specified.
>   As each instruction is examined Docker will look for an existing image
>   in its cache that it can reuse, rather than creating a new (duplicate)
>   image. If you do not want to use the cache at all you can use the
>   --no-cache=true option on the docker build command.

Comment: It seems: "docker build --no-cache ." worked .. Is that what you meant? You suggested the opposite (using cache).